# How do I fix a Perforce change submitted with the wrong job?

Tags: perforce

I submitted a change with the wrong job. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I clean things up when I accidentally associate a change with the wrong job:

1. `'p4 fix -d -c <change> <wrongjob>'`
2. `'p4 fix -c <change> <rightjob>'`

That is, I delete the fix which related the change to the wrong job, and add the fix which relates the change to the desired job.

Note that associating the change to the wrong job may have unintentionally changed the job status from "open" to "fixed" or "closed" (depending on how your job tracking system is configured), and so I also run `'p4 job <wrongjob>'` and check the job status and reset it if it should be reset to "open".